# Close a Coroutine channel when consumer's Job is cancelled

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a simple producer and a consumer that use Coroutine channels. Here is a dumbed down version:

```
class Producer {

  suspend fun start(): ReceiveChannel<String> {

    val channel = Channel<String>(Channel.UNLIMITED)

    // Asynchronous channel.send(it) from an object callback

    channel.invokeOnClose {
      // Channel is closed...
    }

    return channel
  }

}

class Consumer : CoroutineScope {

  private val producer = Producer()

  private val job = Job()
  override val coroutineContext = job + Dispatchers.Default

  fun start() {
    launch {
      val channel = producer.start()

      for (currentValue in channel) {
        // use currentValue
      }
    }
  }

  fun stop() {
    job.cancel()
  }

}
```

The `Producer` create a channel, then fills it with values from an async job. The `Consumer` iterates over it and uses the values.

My expectation was that when I call `job.cancel()` from the consumer, the channel iterator would throw and the channel would be closed. The `invokeOnClose` callback is never called.

I could maintain a reference to the channel in the `Consumer` and do `channel.close()`. I want to know if there is a more clever solution to this. Maybe another way to iterate over the channel's values? Thanks?

**Edit**

It looks like using

```
launch {
    val channel = producer.start()

    channel.consumeEach { currentValue ->
    // use currentValue
    }
}
```

Would do the trick. However `consumeEach()` is marked as Obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You expect that `job.cancel()` will propagate to your producer, but `Producer` is actually not related to anything. Marking function as `suspend` doesn't make it a coroutine.

Here's one way to fix this with structured concurrency:

```
class Producer: CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Job() + Dispatchers.Default

    suspend fun start() = produce<String> {
        channel.send("A")

        channel.invokeOnClose {
            println("Closed")
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `Producer` is aware of `CoroutineScope`.

And since we're using `produce`, you don't need to initialize your channel, as you did before.

Comment: With this method, the channel is closed as soon as I leave `produce()`. I want to keep it alive because the `channel.send()` are asynchronous. They come from a callback from an object that I don't own. I updated my sample to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you want to create a new `Job` on each access of `coroutineContext`?

Comment: @Jonas Channel is closed when you tell it to close. In your case, you probably want to wrap `channel.send()` in either a loop over incoming channel or as a callback listener.

Comment: `channel.send()` is indeed called from a callback listener of Android Fused Location Provider. But right when the code returns from `produce()`, the channel is closed and the callback never has a chance to send values.